# what's the difference between 返事 and 答え？

Tags: word-choice, vocabulary

both have the similar English of "answer," but when do you use one over the other?

Answer (score 12):

From goo both [答え](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/leaf/jn2/79626/m0u/%E7%AD%94%E3%81%88/) and [返事](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/leaf/jn2/200324/m0u/%E8%BF%94%E4%BA%8B/) can have the meaning of "呼びかけに対して答える言葉", which is what "answer" or "response" is used for in English.

But 答え has another meaning "問題・設問などを解いて出される結果", which what I would summarize as equivalent to "solution", while 返事 has "返答の手紙", which is equivalent to "reply".

I guess I could say that 答え is answer to a call/address or a question, while 返事 is answer to a call/address or a letter. Or put it another way, you can use 答え or 返事 interchangeably when referring to answering a call/address but for a solution to a question or problem 答え should be use, and for answering a letter 返事 should be used.

Comment: Thanks, that helps to put those in perspective when one is used as a solution to a problem, and the other is a response to a letter, or something similar.

I'm finding that there are a lot of words that need to be put into context like these two. :)

Comment: 答え is an answer to a question, 返事 is a reply (to a letter, most often).